What is the difference between function overloading and multiple dispatch?
I'm playing around with Julia and it is very much focused around multiple dispatch for function calls. What I cannot understand is - I know there's a conceptual difference between multiple dispatch and overloading but the concepts appear to be very similar at first glance.
C++ has overloading but no multiple dispatch so we I can use the overloading example from wiki on volume calculations:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int Volume(int s) {  // Volume of a cube.
  return s * s * s;
}

double Volume(double r, int h) {  // Volume of a cylinder.
  return 3.1415926 * r * r * static_cast<double>(h);
}

long Volume(long l, int b, int h) {  // Volume of a cuboid.
  return l * b * h;
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << Volume(10);
  std::cout << "\n";
  std::cout << Volume(2.5, 8);
  std::cout << "\n";
  std::cout << Volume(100l, 75, 15);
}

But I can do exactly the same thing with multiple dispatch in Julia, it will look almost exactly the same and give the same result:
function volume(s:: Int64)
    s * s * s
end

function volume(r:: Float64, h:: Int64)
    pi * r * r * h
end

function volume(l:: Int64, b:: Int64, h:: Int64)
    l * b * h
end

volume(10)
volume(2.5, 8)
volume(1001, 75, 15)

It all looks very similar and in practice gives the same result, but Wikipedia is adamant that these are very different, but I cannot understand the reasoning provided:

Multiple dispatch should be distinguished from function overloading,
in which static typing information, such as a term's declared or
inferred type (or base type in a language with subtyping) is used to
determine which of several possibilities will be used at a given call
site, and that determination is made at compile or link time[...]

How would the application know at compile time what values it will need to process and, therefore, which of the function variants to use?

In C++, which unlike Julia is a strongly typed language, the specific values are not important for function overloading. The types of the parameters (whether literal constants or variables), and the number of parameters are how the compiler decides which overload to use.

No knowledge of Julia, but the difference here is between static and dynamic types. Overloading is based on static types, dispatch is based on dynamic types. Your example is confusing because in that case the static and dynamic types are the same. Note that C++ does have single dispatch (aka polymorphism) but not the multiple dispatch that Julia has.

julia doesn't compile functions directly to machine code, instead the function definitions gets converted into something like a template, and at runtime this template is instantiated at the call site with the arguments, even if it is strongly typed. this way julia can save compilation time, because in julia all functions are Jitted and it will takes minutes to jit everything that is not used. on the other hand C++ is entirely precompiled, C++ language doesn't support JIT compilation (unlike julia and C# for instance which have facilities to Jit compile new code at runtime within the language)

in julia most of the time you don't need to strongly type everything, you can get away with just specifying that those are numbers, or arbitrary floats (which could be 32 or 64 or 128 bytes), and so the code is more customizable in the future, 32 bit floats could be twice as fast when very high accuracy is not required, also float16 is popular in GPUs and julia supports running those functions on the GPU, so the same algorithm that accepts an arbitrary float can use float16 on the gpu.

@jkb Both Julia and C++ are strongly typed, in fact Julia may be considered more strongly typed than C++. The difference is that C++ has static types while Julia has dynamic types.

To really explain this, you would have to see an example function which takes arguments as abstract types. For example, you may define a function which takes a parameter x, which has no type (in other words, the type is Any).
You define your algorithm in this function. If at some later point, you want an implementation of that algorithm for some other type, and the logic of the algorithm has to be different, then you can define another version of this function with a more specific constraint on the type for x, which might be an abstract, or concrete, type.

The difference to C++ is that in C++ you do not have abstract types. (At least not in the same way, you cannot write a function which takes an abstract base class as an argument type. Even if you could, an ABC is not really the same as an abstract type in Julia, it's just a class which has some functions the body of which is not defined.) So you can't really show a like-for-like example between Julia and C++.
